# Как подружить Django-registration и abstract user?

Tags: django

Переопределил модель `User`:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Баланс')
    usergroups = models.ForeignKey(UserGroup, verbose_name='Группа', blank=True, null=True)
```

django-registration при регистрации пишет что `Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'personalarea.User'`,

В `settings.py` следующее:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'personalarea.User'
```

В админке выводится нормально, просмотрел исходники django-registration, там используется `get_user_model`, по идее должно обращаться к нужной модели.

Ошибка в `views.py`:

```
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.registration_allowed():
        return redirect(self.disallowed_url)
    return super(RegistrationView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Проект новый, база данных чистая, модель можно менять без последствий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему так, унаследовал форму от RegistrationForm и добавил в Meta model = User, где user получен из функции get_user_model()